# Python Identifier Issue with Tuple & For Loop

Tags: python, opencv

I am currently trying to store (2) values into 2 1D tuples for OpenCV usage thereafter. However, as I am extremely new to Python, I am currently facing a rather "simple" problem regarding the tuple identifier. When I ran the following codes:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

cap= cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)

point1 = []
point2 = []

while True:
     _,frame= cap.read()

     hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

     lower_red = np.array([0,50,120])
     upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])

     lower_yellow = np.array([25,70,120])
     upper_yellow = np.array([30,255,255])

     lower_blue = np.array([90,60,0])
     upper_blue = np.array([121,255,255])

     maskred = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_red,upper_red)
     maskyellow = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_yellow,upper_yellow)
     maskblue = cv2.inRange(hsv,lower_blue,upper_blue)

     cntsred = cv2.findContours(maskred, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     cntsred = imutils.grab_contours(cntsred)

     cntsyellow = cv2.findContours(maskyellow, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     cntsyellow = imutils.grab_contours(cntsyellow)

     cntsblue = cv2.findContours(maskblue, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     cntsblue = imutils.grab_contours(cntsblue)

     for c in cntsred:
         areared = cv2.contourArea(c)
         if areared > 5000:


             cv2.drawContours(frame,[c],-1,(0,255,0), 3)

             M = cv2.moments(c)

             cxred = int(M["m10"]/ M["m00"])
             cyred = int(M["m01"]/ M["m00"])

             cv2.circle(frame,(cxred,cyred),7,(255,255,255),-1)
             cv2.putText(frame, "Red", (cxred-20, cyred-20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2.5, (255, 255, 255), 3)
             redcoord = (cxred, cyred)

     for c in cntsyellow:
         areayellow = cv2.contourArea(c)
         if areayellow > 5000:


             cv2.drawContours(frame,[c],-1,(0,255,0), 3)

             M = cv2.moments(c)

             cxyellow = int(M["m10"]/ M["m00"])
             cyyellow = int(M["m01"]/ M["m00"])

             cv2.circle(frame,(cxyellow,cyyellow),7,(255,255,255),-1)
             cv2.putText(frame, "Yellow", (cxyellow-20, cyyellow-20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2.5, (255, 255, 255), 3)
             yellowcoord = (cxyellow, cyyellow)

     cv2.line(frame, redcoord, yellowcoord, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

There was the following syntax error as shown in the image.

[image]

May I check whether it is due to some indent or declaration issue that caused the "yellowcoord" tuple to be unidentified?

Comment: `yellowcoord` is defined inside an if-block in a for loop. If the contents of the if-block are never run (i.e. if `areayellow` is never greater than 5000), then `yellowcoord` will not be defined.

Comment: Hi @khelwood, right that makes sense, thanks for pointing it out. In that case, may I check whether there is any way to declare them as a global variable? I tried experimenting with a simple code as shown below but still receive the num1 undefined error on "if num1 is None:" even though it has been declared using a global keyword at line 1. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Af8kodJpvK8R_Qkm8P2fobt47hTn4AD8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You could set it to None before your loop, and then after the loop before you try and use it check `if yellowcoord is not None:`.

Comment: Hey @khelwood oh right that works! Sorry, I am not familiar enough to think of that just yet, but really appreciate the help. I just wanted to check as well regarding value passing in Python, based on the image (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OKCH4Y_LbIO6gmL_wVOmN4wgpVl5ePuX/view?usp=sharing), shouldn't Line 27 print out (6, 8) instead of (None, None) due to the re-intialization of variables at Line 17-18? Sorry again for yet another elementary question.

Comment: I'm not looking at your google drive. Feel free to post a new question if you have a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yellowcoord` is defined inside an if-block in a for loop. If the contents of the if-block are never run (i.e. if `areayellow` is never greater than 5000), then `yellowcoord` will not be defined.

You can check for this contingency by initialising `yellowcoord` to None before the loop, and then testing after the loop if it has been given another value:

```
yellowcoord = None

for c in cntsyellow:
     areayellow = cv2.contourArea(c)
     if areayellow > 5000:
        ... 
        yellowcoord = (cxyellow, cyyellow) 

if yellowcoord is not None:
    # Now I know I can use yellowcoord safely
```

Comment: Hi @khyelwood, thanks once again for answering this logic query, really appreciate it! J